# How to Loop and Print 2D array using Java 8

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-8

Consider this two dimentional array

```
String[][] names = { {"Sam", "Smith"},
                     {"Robert", "Delgro"},
                     {"James", "Gosling"},
                   };
```

Using the classic way, if we want to access each element of a two dimensional array, then we need to iterate through two dimensional array using two for loops.

```
for (String[] a : names) {
    for (String s : a) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Is there a new elegant way to loop and Print 2D array using Java 8 features (Lambdas,method reference,Streams,...)?

What I have tried so far is this:

```
Arrays.asList(names).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@6ce253f1
[Ljava.lang.String;@53d8d10a
[Ljava.lang.String;@e9e54c2
```

Comment: How do your `String`s become `int`s in the middle of your operation?

Comment: Ooops sorry. I have edited the code from `for (int[] a : names) {
    for (int i : a) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}` to `for (String[] a : names) {
          for (String s : a) {
            System.out.println(s);
           }
     }` Thanks @Holger

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keeping the same output as your `for` loops:

```
Stream.of(names)
    .flatMap(Stream::of)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(See [`Stream#flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).)

Also something like:

```
Arrays.stream(names)
    .map(a -> String.join(" ", a))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which produces output like:

```
Sam Smith
Robert Delgro
James Gosling
```

(See [`String#join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).)

Also:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.stream(names)
        .map(a -> String.join(" ", a))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
);
```

Which produces output like:

```
Sam Smith, Robert Delgro, James Gosling
```

(See [`Collectors#joining`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-).)

Joining is one of the less discussed but still wonderful new features of Java 8.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
Stream.of(names).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 10):

In standard Java

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(names));
```

Comment: Very nice, but is there a new way using java 8 features?

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 using `Streams` and `forEach`:

```
    Arrays.stream(names).forEach((i) -> {
        Arrays.stream(i).forEach((j) -> System.out.print(j + " "));
        System.out.println();
    });
```

The first `forEach` acts as outer loop while the next as inner loop.

This gives the following output:

```
Sam Smith 
Robert Delgro 
James Gosling
```