# How can I print this 2d array of strings in this form without too much effort (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, output, field

I'm trying to create the "cat finds mouse" thing myself but I have troubles doing it because the way I print the field is pretty complicated / inefficient.

So I have the field:

```
String[][]field = {
            {"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"},
            {"+", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "M", "+"},
            {"+", " ", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", " ", "+", "+", " ", " ", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", " ", " ", " ", " ", "+", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", " ", " ", "+", "+", "+", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", "C", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "+"},
            {"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"},
        };
```

And it is supposed to be printed like this:

```
+++++++++
+      M+
+ +++++ +
+ ++  + +
+    ++ +
+  ++++ +
+C      +
+++++++++
```

Here is my code how I print it like that. The print is very fine as desired but the way it is coded and done is very inefficient... Isn't there a way to do all that with just few lines of code? Please note that it must look exactly as I posted.

Here is my way:

```
public class CatMouseCheap {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][]field = {
            {"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"},
            {"+", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "M", "+"},
            {"+", " ", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", " ", "+", "+", " ", " ", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", " ", " ", " ", " ", "+", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", " ", " ", "+", "+", "+", "+", " ", "+"},
            {"+", "C", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "+"},
            {"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"},
        };

        for(int i=0; i<field.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<field[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(field[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is inefficient ?

Comment: I would say, that this is O(n) complexity and it won't get any better. :-)

Comment: This is as efficient as it can get. Maybe using a stringbuilder instead of seperated characters would make it slightly faster, but that's not noticeable.

Comment: @Berger because I want find the shortest way from cat to mouse. And in these 2 for loops I have big troubles doing it :s Edit: And this shouldn't be O(n), rather O(n^2) or am I wrong?

Comment: @cnmesr It is O(n), because the number of iterations is equal to number of elements. It would be O(n^2) if you would e.g. iterate over all elements and compare each of them to all others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(
            Arrays.stream(field)
                .map(a -> String.join("", a))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Works with java8

Comment: I know of this. But the output is horrible, it isn't as I described in my question : / Maybe there is a way to modify it? Edit: I didn't downvote!

Comment: @cnmesr Sorry I missed it.

Comment: Changed to java8. Hope this helps

Comment: Haha so good, I hope it will also help finding the shortest way from cat to mouse. I mean the 2 for loops I used made a lot things harder to code it, If I imagined all correctly. But this is very nice already, to see another way, thank you :)

Comment: Java 8 makes it happen. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065577/how-to-loop-and-print-2d-array-using-java-8 for more info. Its very similar